# Setting issue to "In Progress" via SVN commit message

Tags: svn, teamcity, youtrack

I'm trying to figure out SVN commit messages in YouTrack. I have linkages between YouTrack and TeamCity set up to work. I can see links ot builds in TC, and links to tickets in TeamCity build histories.

I'm doing an SVN commit with "ID-xx In Progress " I see documentation from JetBrains about how format a command, but basically no information on what the possible commands are.

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD5/Executing+Commands+from+Comment+to+VCS+Commit
http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD5/Mapping+Issues+to+VCS+Change+Commit

How do I do a commit code and set a ticket to be "in progress" as the state?

When clicking the '?' on the TeamCity tab of the ticket, the message indicates:

```
This change's comment does not contain any command. For more info please see the documentation.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prefix issue id with either # or ^ to make YouTrack consider what follows the id as a command. So in your case it will be "#ID-xx In Progress" or "^ID-xx In Progress"